# Dreamweaver command to set location of fileview

Tags: dreamweaver

is there a way to locate a specific file in the fielview of director via a shell command?

I open a file (test.php) like this in dreamweaver, using an other application:

```
"C:\Program Files\Dreamweaver.exe c:\test.php"
```

But the fileview listing the local files does not jump to the opened file.

Maybe I can write a script and launch this script via shell to locate the file in the fileview?

Thanks for help or hints!

Comment: Can I ask what the specific reason(s) that you want to have the file selected? There may be other options for you depending on what you actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about having the file opened via the command line automatically become selected in the *Files* panel.

I am aware of no documented method of getting Dreamweaver to perform operations from the command line.

About the closest you're going to easily get to would be to assign a keyboard shortcut to Site -> Locate in Site via Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac?) -> Keyboard Shortcuts. I'm not aware of it, but there may be some way to send an a specific application keystrokes via the command line.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your hint 'Site -> Locate in Site'. That helps me much!